# Issues printing char array after reading from File

Tags: c, arrays, gcc

The array var[i] reads the names of all drives from the log.txt and prints it on the screen. After that, the array is printed again until the '\0' is reached only the first character is printed.Dont know why?

```
FILE *fp;
char  var[512];
i = 0;

if (fp = fopen("log.txt", "r+")) {
    while (fscanf(fp, "%c", &var[i]) != EOF) {
        printf("%c", var[i]);    -----------> Works Fine
        i++;
    }
}

fclose(fp);
printf("\n\n");

i = 0;
while(var[i] != '\0') {
    printf("%c",var[i]);        ------------------> Problem
    i++;
}
```

Output:

```
■N a m e
 C :
 D :
 E :
 F :
 G :


  ■N         -------------> Problem
```

Comment: `var` does not contain the `\0` termination, the second loop stops randomly or you program may even crash. If you are reading single characters, don't use `fscanf`, ise `fgetc` instead. It's always better to use `fgets` to read the whole line and then parse it.

Comment: Another thing that I don't like it, is that you assume that the file `log.txt` contains no more than 512 bytes. It's dangerous to assume such a thing, in general you should treat user input (and that also mean files) as not trustworthy. You'll avoid painful bugs that way.

Comment: @Pablo Imagine the size of log.txt is unknown.In such a case I can only assign a max size to array.

Comment: you can, but you shouldn't. You should dynamically allocate space and when you realize that there is not enough space in the buffer (because `EOF` is not reached), you should assign even more space (with `realloc`). Assume a fixed size file, because no one would ever think of passing something else, is naive at best. That will eventually bite your ass.

Answer (score 1):

You never write the `'\0'`, for which the `while`-loop then is looking for. 
So write

```
...
var[i] = '\0';
fclose(fp);
...
```

after the first loop where you read in the characters and it should work.

Alternatively (or additionally), you could initialise your array such that it is "pre-filled" with `0`, like:

```
char  var[512] = { 0 };  // will set all 512 characters to 0.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but its not working. The o/p is still the same.

Comment: then your example here and your code are not the same. I made copy and paste of your code except the `char  var[512] = { 0 }; ` line and it worked as it should. The `log.txt` is actually 8 bytes long. Perhaps yours in longer that 512 and hence you see weird problems which what you get when you assume that the input will never be longer than your fixed size.

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove i=0; before loop because it will initialise it to zero thats why only single character is printed

Comment: No, the problem is that `\0` was never written in `var`, removing (I assume you mean) the second `i=0` makes it even worse, because now you start reading even beyond what was written in the first place